# find the original key of groupby in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, key

```
var aaa = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Select(o => new { o }).ToList();
var bbb = aaa.Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
//There is a error of `Key`
```

Does that mean the `Key` is only allowed for the original List after `GroupBy`. Is it possible to obtain the `Key` for any `Select` after `GroupBy`?(Surely, we can storge the `Key = o.Key` in the `Select` )

Furthermore,

```
var aaa = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Select(o => o.ToList()}).ToList();
```

If we change `aaa` into two dimensional `List`, Is it possible to obtain the previous `Key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first linq expression, in the `Select` you are wrapping the `IGrouping` object that you got from the `GroupBy` with a new anonymous object. 
So to get that `Key` property in your second line you should:

```
//Original:
var bbb = aaa.Select(o => o.Key).ToList();

//Change to:
var bbb = aaa.Select(o => o.o.Key).ToList();
```

For second question, if you want to get the `Key` in this case:

```
//Original:
var aaa = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date)
              .Select(o => o.ToList()})
              .ToList();

//Then you should:
var aaa = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date)
              .Select(o => o.ToList()})
              .Select(x => o.FirstOrDefault().Date)
              .ToList();
```

Reason being is that:

- You group your items by `Date`
- First select you convert a IGrouping into a `List<YourClass>` but now you have an `IEnumerable<List<YourClass>>` where each record in the `IEnumerable`, all the inner items will have the same date
- In second `Select` - take whichever item in the inner collections - and get the `Date` it is the same as getting the `Key` in the example before

---

To achieve what you actually what to get (grouping by the date and getting for each group the symbols):

```
var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.Date)
                 .Select(group => new { group.Key, Symbols = group.Select(item => item.Symbol).ToList() });

//Or using a different overload of the `GroupBy`:
var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.Date,
                          (key,group) => return new { Key = key, Symbols = group.Select(item => item.Symbol).ToList() });
```

Comment: sorry for the second question, suppose you don't know `aaa` is `groupby` `date` before, then how do you know the `Key`

Comment: @user6703592 - you don't. If you don't know it was grouped, and by now the collection isn't an `IGrouping<,>` then their are no keys.. - The `Key` property exists only if the result is an `IGrouping` (or wrapping such an object like in your first case)

Comment: So, `var aaa = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Select(o => o.Select(p =>new { p.Symbol})).ToList();` such case supppose we lose the whole information,  Is it possible to obtain the previous Key?

Comment: @user6703592 - No, but from what it seems you are trying to `GroupBy` `Date` and then get for each group only the `Symbol` values right?

Comment: @ Gilad Green yes, so it is impossible to  obtain the previous Key in this case.

Comment: @  Gilad Green ok! So in Summary, we have to storage the first level `o` of `groupby`, otherwise  it is impossible to obtain the previous Key?

Comment: @user6703592 - No, I prefer to keep the explanation to the general case - if you `GroupBy` and then you convert your result to something else than an `IGrouping<,>` without keeping aside the `Key` then you loose it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your incorrect syntax. You crated an anonymous object, so you need to access the property with instance name. So you should be doing this.

```
var bbb = aaa.Select(o => o.o.Key).ToList();
```

> if we change aaa into two dimensional List, Is it possible to obtain
>   the previous Key?

No, because you have groped values collection not the `Key`. So result will not contain `Key`.